# Iterating through list for finding a substring in an if statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, substring

I have a list of strings:

```
relations = ['displays', '1000displays', 'chooses', '1011chooses', '1020displays', 'clicks', '1031clicks', 'add to', 'checks', '1040checks', 'inserts discount offer to', '1050inserts discount offer to', 'inserts']
```

And a substring:

```
t_object = 'discount offer'
```

And I want to execute the code in the if block only if the string `discount offer` is not present in the `relations` list.

I have the following code but since `discount offer` is present in the `relations`, it should not step into the code block in the if statement, but it does. Why?

```
if len(t_object) > len(objects[sentence_number]) and (s for s in relations if t_object not in s):
     print('I am in but I shoudlt be.')
```

Comment: The bit after the `and` is a generator function, which is always 'truthy'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `any()` function.

```
if len(t_object) > len(objects[sentence_number]) and not any(t_object in s for s in relations):
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` at the end, and I am getting `unresolved reference s`.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, so and you are also missing `not` before `any` just so it answers my question.